# Union distinct in Hive

Tags: hive, hql, union, hue

How do I combine rows while removing duplicate rows?

I tried `UNION` by itself as well as `UNION DISTINCT` but both returned error messages in Hue.

> error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 5:10
>   mismatched input 'distinct' expecting all near 'union' in set operator

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product1.user)
FROM product1
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT(product2.user)
FROM product2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(product3.user)
FROM product3
```

Comment: Just use union.  `Select product1.user from product1 union select user from product2 ...`.  `Union` automatically removes duplicates.  `Union all` keeps them.

Comment: I tried union  by itself and got error: `error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 4:4 missing all at 'select' near '' line 7:4 missing all at 'select' near ''`

Comment: Are you on a version prior to 1.2?  If so, only union all is supported.  If so, you'll have to use union all, and wrap an outer query around it for the distinct.  `select distinct user from (select user from product1 union all select user from product2...) t`.

Comment: On 1.0.0, thanks @Andrew

Comment: Thanks @Andew it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @Andrew in the comments above:

If you are on a Hive version prior to 1.2, only `union all` is supported. So you'll have to use `union all`, and wrap an outer query around it for the distinct:

> select distinct user from (select user from product1 union all select user from product2...) t